# Execute Fade-In as Page initially  loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, implementation, fadein

I am working on some jQuery code to apply page transitions. What i want the jQuery code to do is basically apply a fade in effect of the page as follows:

```
$("body").css("display", "none");
$("body")().fadeIn(400);
```

Once the page loads the page reloads and then does the instructed fade in effect, but what I want to happen is a fade in effect for the whole webpage right from the start and tried:

`$(document).load(function() {`

However, this does not work. I also tried this code to no avail:

```
$("body").load().css("display", "none");
$("body").load().fadeIn(400);
```

Are there any visible error in my code blocks that can be rectified to apply the desired behavior or can the community please direct me to a guide that demonstrates the correct implementation of what I am aiming to do?

Answer (score 2):

You could place this in a `.css` file -

```
body { display:none; }
```

Or even place it inline like so -

```
<body style="display:none;" >
```

And then in a `$(document).ready()` callback fade it in using this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").fadeIn(400);
});
```

The browser will render the HTML according to your `css` file first.  So when the browser comes to render the `<body>` tag, it'll see a css rule saying that its `display` property must be set to `none`.  Only after all the HMTL is loaded **and** jQuery is ready (`$(document).ready()`) then you can call your `fadeIn()`;

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to set the whole page to invisible or hidden:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

Or:

```
body {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

You can set this as inline CSS inside the `<head>`. Then inside jQuery you can make it fade in once loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
//    $("body")().fadeIn(400); // this is incorrect, try with:
$('body').fadeIn(400);
```

That means:

```
$("body").css("display", "none");

$(window).load(function(){  // use "window"
  $('body').fadeIn(400);
});
```

Or you may try to set `display:none;` directly from your CSS (depends on your needs)

```
body{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the load on window and not on DOM.

Try :

```
   $(window).load(function(){

    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(400);

})
```

And for further explination try [Here](http://blog.eizesus.com/2009/03/jquery-s-ready-runs-before-load-event/)